# How can I update this legacy glyphicons to work with Bootstrap 5's FontAwesome?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5, glyphicons

The following code works well using Bootstrap 3, but when I update to Bootstrap 5, the glyphicon doesn't work.

The following is the HTML, which renders nice radio buttons. When an option is checked, it should show a nice glyphicon, but this doesn't work in Bootstrap 5. How can I update this code to work with Bootstrap 5?

```
<ul class="chec-radio">
    <li class="pz">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" checked="" id="pro-chx-residential" name="property_type" class="pro-chx" value="constructed">
            <div class="clab">Beginner</div>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li class="pz">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" id="pro-chx-commercial" name="property_type" class="pro-chx" value="unconstructed" checked>
            <div class="clab">Intermediate</div>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li class="pz">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" id="pro-chx-open" name="property_type" class="pro-chx" value="open_land">
            <div class="clab">Advanced</div>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is the CSS:

```
ul.chec-radio {
    margin: 15px;
}
ul.chec-radio li.pz {
    display: inline;
}
.chec-radio label.radio-inline input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
.chec-radio label.radio-inline input[type="checkbox"]:checked+div {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}
.chec-radio .radio-inline .clab {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #e7e7e7;
    padding: 7px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #333;
    position: relative;
    height: 34px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.chec-radio label.radio-inline input[type="checkbox"]:checked+div:before {
    content: "\e013";
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
}
.chec-radio label.radio-inline input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}
.chec-radio label.radio-inline input[type="radio"]:checked+div {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}
.chec-radio label.radio-inline input[type="radio"]:checked+div:before {
    content: "\e013";
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Updated code using bootstrap 5

```css
ul.chec-radio {
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.chec-radio li.pz {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.chec-radio .radio-inline .clab {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #e7e7e7;
  padding: 7px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #333;
  position: relative;
  height: 34px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.chec-radio label.radio-inline input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.chec-radio label.radio-inline input[type="checkbox"]:checked+div {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}

.chec-radio label.radio-inline input[type="checkbox"]:checked+div:before,
.chec-radio label.radio-inline input[type="radio"]:checked+div:before {
  content: "\f00c";
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
}

.chec-radio label.radio-inline input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.chec-radio label.radio-inline input[type="radio"]:checked+div {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Bootstrap 5 Radio Buttons</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="chec-radio">
    <li class="pz">
      <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" checked="" id="pro-chx-residential" name="property_type" class="pro-chx" value="constructed">
                <div class="clab">Beginner</div>
            </label>
    </li>
    <li class="pz">
      <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" id="pro-chx-commercial" name="property_type" class="pro-chx" value="unconstructed" checked>
                <div class="clab">Intermediate</div>
            </label>
    </li>
    <li class="pz">
      <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" id="pro-chx-open" name="property_type" class="pro-chx" value="open_land">
                <div class="clab">Advanced</div>
            </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```